# Add autogenerated Column to gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have AutoGenrated SerialNo of my Gridview in RowDatabound event like below..

```
 protected void Gdview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lblSerial = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSRNO");
                lblSerial.Text = "S" + ((Gdview.PageIndex * Gdview.PageSize) + e.Row.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Now i Want to Add this Text to my SQL Column..this SeirlNo is first Column ,,i followed Below procedure to add the values to the Sql Table...

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strOrganization = txtOrganization.Text;
            string strOrigin = txtOrigin.Text;
            string strLoc = TexLocation.Text;
            string strService = TxtService.Text;
            string strEst = TxtEstablish.Text;

            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("Insert into mpSoftware Organization='"+strOrganization+"'",Origin='"++"',Location='"++"',Service='"++"',Est='"++"' Where SerialNo='"++"');
```

.....
....
...

But here i strucked..i fogotted that SerialNo is autogenrated..how wud i get the SerialNo value here???? Give me some valuable suggestions plz...

```
        }
```

Comment: Would you [edit] your question to show the markup for the Button and the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property to hold the value of the Serial No when it is generated. Then pass that value into your sqlCommand

Comment: Can you please Give me some example i will understand in a betterway please...??